# Guardar id de último registro insertado en variable de procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

¿Cómo puedo seleccionar el ultimo `id` registrado de la tabla `students` y guardarla en un variable?

Tengo esta estructura:

```
-- variables
declare idStudent int(11);
```

Consulta:

```
select id into idStudent from students where last_insert_id();
    if found_rows() = 0 then        
        set result = 2; 
    end if;
```

¿Es la manera correcta?

Comment: Qué motor de BD estas utilizando?

Comment: ¿Qué uso final le darás a `idStudent`? No es necesario hacer un `select` del `id` (que lo estás haciendo mal por no hacer una comparación) porque `last_insert_id()` te devolverá precisamente ese `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es asignar el valor devuelto por [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) a la variable que has definido con un [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html):

```
SET idStudent := LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

He usado el operador de asignación [`:=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value) para evitar ambigüedad de uso.

PD: No es necesario hacer un `SELECT` del campo `id` como planteas y, además, tu consulta está mal porque deberías comparar un campo con el valor devuelto por `LAST_INSERT_ID()` en el `WHERE` o, en caso contrario, todos los registros de la tabla serán devueltos uno tras otro porque la condición se supone cierta cuando `LAST_INSERT_ID()` devuelve un valor diferente de `0`.

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL sería algo así:

```
SELECT MAX(id) INTO idStudent FROM students;
```

Comment: En un entorno con inserciones concurrentes esa consulta podría devolver el `id` insertado por otra consulta diferente, no la tuya.

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia, realmente pregunta por el último dato insertado, no especifica que necesariamente sea el suyo :) En cualquier caso, no nos dejes con la duda, ¿hay forma de obtener el que acabas de insertar? Con transacciones, quizás...

Comment: Mucho más sencillo que eso. En su pregunta hace uso de la función existente para ello, `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, por eso entiendo que quiere obtener el `id` de la suya. En mi respuesta está el uso correcto y el enlace a la documentación. Un saludo.